# How to search for initial straight double quoting character in RegEx?

Tags: regex, xcode, swift

I would like to use RegEx to find straight quotes `"` in a text and then convert them to smart (curved) quotes where the opening quotes are different from the closing quotes (something also known as "educating quotes").

Finding all the straight quotes is easy; I just search for `\"`

The problem is that I would like to discriminate between the opening and closing ones. Is this feasible?

**EDIT**
I'm using Swift on Xcode. Currently I'm using something like this:

```
let myPattern = "\""
let newStr = applyRegex(originalText, pattern: myPattern, newString: "myString")
```

Comment: probably you want to [use a capture group for what's inside the double quotes](https://regex101.com/r/wS8dS2/2).

Comment: language you are using?

Comment: Hi rock321987, Swift on Xcode

Comment: i have not used swift ever..but you can put `"(.*)"` pattern and replace the pattern with `"“\\1”"` or ``"“$1”"``

Comment: Hi @rock321987, what I would like to do is search for a double quote character at the beginning of a word, like in **"word** and then replace it with a curve double quote, like **“word**. Then in a separate code replace the ending quote like in **word"** and replace it with a curve quote, like in **word"**. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: `where the opening quotes are different from the closing quotes` Questions: 1 Is the text from a language that supports quoting? 2. If so, does it support escaped quotes? 3. Are the quotes supposed to be _balanced_ (i.e. each open has a close), that require validation ? 4. If language, can quotes be hidden by comments ? If you answer yes to any of these, you can't do it like this.

Comment: Yes, it will be possible, but you can do both replacement in a single replace statement

Answer (score 2):

Command:

```
sed -e 's/"\([^"]*\)"/“\1”/g'
```

Input:

```
"a"-"b"
```

Output:

```
“a”-“b”
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using using Swift on Xcode.